# Convert a generic array to a specific type

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm using Interop to work with Excel in C#. I need two cells. This is how I get them:

```
cells = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range("V" + i, "W" + i);
System.Array values = (System.Array)cells.Cells.Value;
```

This returns the values I want, as tested with a `foreach` loop. But how do I get the elements into `string` variables? I tried this:

```
var stringValues = values.Cast<string>();
```

but I can't access it in any way without raising an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `ConvertAll` should suffice:

```
var stringValues = Array.ConvertAll(values, item => (string)item);
```

Answer (score 0):

the code `var stringValues = values.Cast<string>();` is attempting to cast the array as a string.  so, if you are trying to end up with an array of strings you can try:

```
var stringValues = new List<string>();

values.ToList().ForEach(cellValue=>stringValues.Add(cellValue.ToString());
```

this is off the top of my head, there is probably a terser way of expressing this

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
values.Select(o => o.ToString());
```